# Como criar um Build.gradle novo?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

Desde que importei meu projeto do gitHub, estou tento esse error:

> Migrate Project to Gradle? This project does not use the Gradle build system. We recommend that you migrate to using the Gradle build system

Um cara ja me disse que preciso criar um build.gradle para adicionar ao projeto, mas n sei como fazer isso. alguem pode me ajudar?

Comment: O seu projeto veio do eclipse?

Comment: Não, ele veio do android studio mesmo

Comment: @CaiqueOliveira O meu projeto veio do Eclipse. Caso vc saiba como fazer vc poderia me ajudar ?

Comment: @VictorHenrique vc deve baixar o projeto e importa ele no android studio através da opção: import project (Eclipse ADT, Gradle,etc.)

Answer (score 1):

## TL;DR

A mensagem é de recomendação, não obrigação, mas vale a pena usar Gradle no projeto.

## Gradle

[Gradle](http://gradle.org/) é uma ferramenta de automação de *build*, isto é, dos processos que envolvem seu código para compilação, empacotamento, testes e distribuição.

Um projeto que usa o Gradle deve ter pelo menos um arquivo `build.gradle` com as configurações necessárias.

IDEs como Eclipse e IntelliJ, esta última a base do [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html), fazem uso da configuração do Gradle para realizar algumas configurações automáticas, embora seja perfeitamente possível realizar essas configurações manualmente, isto é, sem o Gradle.

Gradle é geralmente [recomendado](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide) para desenvolvimento Android ao invés de configuração manual, pois facilita grandemente o desenvolvimento e padroniza os procedimentos para compilar e distribuir o projeto.

## Exemplo de configuração simples

A [documentação dá um exemplo de uma configuração simples](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Simple-build-files) para um projeto Android:

```groovy
buildscript {
    repositories { 
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.1.0'
}
```

## Build Init Plugin

Para alguns tipos de projetos comuns, há um plugin do Gradle que permite gerar a configuração básica: [Build Init Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_init_plugin.html). Por exemplo, se você tiver o Gradle instalado você pode executar o seguinte em linha de comando:

```
gradle init --type java-library
```

A configuração básica será criada de acordo com o tipo (`type`) de projeto. Entretanto, este plugin ainda está em processo de incubação e ainda não tem opção para um projeto Android. Além disso, a configuração é básica e provavelmente alterações mais específicas serão necessárias.

Claro que cada projeto pode ter diferentes configurações e provavelmente você vai precisar percorrer um pouco a documentação para pegar todos os detalhes.

## Considerações

Automação de build é algo que pode dar uma dor de cabeça no começo, principalmente na primeira vez que se faz, mas é algo que se paga com o tempo.

Nesse ponto, algumas poucas vezes se pode confiar nas IDEs ou ferramentas para gerar uma configuração básica, mas não recomendo depender disso ou seguir sempre por esse caminho. É melhor gastar um pouco de tempo para entender o básico de como o Gradle funciona.